how does weighted shortest distance modifies if two nodes are made into one
Let us say I have a bipartite network with developer and projects and nodes . And let the weights of network be the  inverse of number of contributions. Say I already have computed the shortest distances. Now if say make some nodes same, ( a couple of developers nodes  ,say a=b, c=d etc) how will the the distances change?

Sorry, I can't understand what you are asking or what the problem set up is.  I suggest [edit]ing the question to make it clearer, and make clear how it is relevant to others, and to show what progress you've made.
